# CalenderView content is not showing

Tags: android, xml, animation, calendar, android-animation

So I am trying show/hide the calenderview on button click.But end up showing the white layout only.

//xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_view"
        android:elevation="@dimen/height4"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <CalendarView
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_view"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </CalendarView>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/date_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           //some other layouts
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know because of i set the calenderview background to the white, but content also should show. Check out the output image[image]

But when I showing the calenderview directly(setting the visibility to visible) it is working perfectly, SO there is no issue in xml.

This is how I am handling the show/hide of calenderview

```
private void setUpCalenderView() {
        isCalenderVisible=!isCalenderVisible;
        if (isCalenderVisible){
            //((CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            ((CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
        else{

            ((CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Edit:

This is the gist of code : https://gist.github.com/ankurtagtaste/692335e71ed0576b1e852292536d0ebf

Comment: what is this `isCalenderVisible=!isCalenderVisible;`?

Comment: basically, initially, I am setting isCalenderVisibile(boolean variable storing the current status of calendar visibility) to false, when user taps just alter the status. @Eminem

Comment: show me your code

Comment: I have pasted the complete code in the question. @Eminem

Comment: bad logic,first remove `isCalenderVisible=!isCalenderVisible;` second create a var so that you dont have to call the `findview...` every time.third create a `boolean` that changes onclick button

Comment: here I have create the complete gist, check out. https://gist.github.com/ankurtagtaste/692335e71ed0576b1e852292536d0ebf @Eminem

Comment: i can only answer in java not kotlin are you interested

Comment: @Eminem check this https://gist.github.com/ankurtagtaste/4c332349dca131f20990c22f4b2c763b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this works perfectly:

```
<CalendarView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cal"
         />
```

the idea is to remove the  `android:visibility="invisible"` from your layout and do it programmatically

```
         cal=x.findViewById(R.id.cal);
         cal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cal.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                        cal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    else
                        cal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change:

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

To make calendar view visible in xml

Instead of changing the visibility with calendar view you can use date picker

Comment: But initially i want to hide the calender

Answer (score 0):

Put the CalendarView on a RelativeLayout and change the visibility of this RelativeLayout. It's work for me.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```